# CSS - How to evaluate the use of classes?

Tags: css

i build a large website in the last months and the constant maintenance of my .css-files have lacked a little bit during this process. Is there any tool which i can use to evaluate my .css file and the use of the defined classes in my project?

I have something in mind where i can select my .css file and the workspace where my project is stored. The tool then searches through all .php/.html files...

Any hint is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) addon of Firefox for that.

> It extracts all the selectors from all the stylesheets on the page
>   you're viewing, then analyzes that page to see which of those
>   selectors are not used. The data is then stored so that when testing
>   subsequent pages, selectors can be crossed off the list as they're
>   encountered.

[image]